# LINQ Select if not null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
int? id = invoices.Where(l => l.OrganisationID == part.OrganisationID)
                  .Select(m => m.TypeID).FirstOrDefault();
```

'invoices' is a `List`

But `invoices.Where(l => l.OrganisationID == part.OrganisationID)` might be null, in which case `id` needs to be a new `Nullable<int>`.

How can I do this in one line (and efficiently) rather than first checking if the object is null or not?

Comment: You mean "empty", and not "null", right?

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
int? id = invoices
    .Where(l.OrganisationID == part.OrganisationID))
    .Select(m => m.TypeID as int?) // add 'as int?'
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I mean if the invoice object is not in the list of invoices, make 'id' null. Honestly I haven't tested my code yet, I just assumed it would throw a null reference exception if the invoice was null before trying to select from it. I'll test this and be back later with my point awards

Comment: @user982119 If `Where` doesn't match any elements it returns empty `IEnumerable`, not a null value.

Comment: Thank you @Dzienny, guess that explains it :)